# Custom Week Column in Power BI starting with conditions in StartofMonth and EndofMonth

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to create a Week column in Dax Calendar table but haven't got any luck.

Conditions:
1.Week starts from Saturday and ends on Friday.
2.If the date is starting on the month beginning then the week should start with it and same goes for month end.

| DATE | WEEK | Explanation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2024 | 1 Jan'24 - 5 Jan'24 | Week starts on 1st day of Month on Monday and week ends on Friday |
| 1/2/2024 | 1 Jan'24 - 5 Jan'24 | Week starts on 1st day of Month on Monday and week ends on Friday |
| 1/3/2024 | 1 Jan'24 - 5 Jan'24 | Week starts on 1st day of Month on Monday and week ends on Friday |
| 1/4/2024 | 1 Jan'24 - 5 Jan'24 | Week starts on 1st day of Month on Monday and week ends on Friday |
| 1/5/2024 | 1 Jan'24 - 5 Jan'24 | Week starts on 1st day of Month on Monday and week ends on Friday |
| 1/6/2024 | 6 Jan'24 - 12 Jan'24 | Week starts on 6th and ends on 12th |
| 1/7/2024 | 6 Jan'24 - 12 Jan'24 | Week starts on 6th and ends on 12th |
| 1/8/2024 | 6 Jan'24 - 12 Jan'24 | Week starts on 6th and ends on 12th |
| 1/9/2024 | 6 Jan'24 - 12 Jan'24 | Week starts on 6th and ends on 12th |
| 1/10/2024 | 6 Jan'24 - 12 Jan'24 | Week starts on 6th and ends on 12th |
| 1/11/2024 | 6 Jan'24 - 12 Jan'24 | Week starts on 6th and ends on 12th |
| 1/12/2024 | 6 Jan'24 - 12 Jan'24 | Week starts on 6th and ends on 12th |
| 1/13/2024 | 13 Jan'24 - 19 Jan'24 | Week starts on 13th and ends on 19th |
| 1/14/2024 | 13 Jan'24 - 19 Jan'24 | Week starts on 13th and ends on 19th |
| 1/15/2024 | 13 Jan'24 - 19 Jan'24 | Week starts on 13th and ends on 19th |
| 1/16/2024 | 13 Jan'24 - 19 Jan'24 | Week starts on 13th and ends on 19th |
| 1/17/2024 | 13 Jan'24 - 19 Jan'24 | Week starts on 13th and ends on 19th |
| 1/18/2024 | 13 Jan'24 - 19 Jan'24 | Week starts on 13th and ends on 19th |
| 1/19/2024 | 13 Jan'24 - 19 Jan'24 | Week starts on 13th and ends on 19th |
| 1/20/2024 | 20 Jan'24 - 26 Jan'24 | Week starts on 20th and ends on 26th |
| 1/21/2024 | 20 Jan'24 - 26 Jan'24 | Week starts on 20th and ends on 26th |
| 1/22/2024 | 20 Jan'24 - 26 Jan'24 | Week starts on 20th and ends on 26th |
| 1/23/2024 | 20 Jan'24 - 26 Jan'24 | Week starts on 20th and ends on 26th |
| 1/24/2024 | 20 Jan'24 - 26 Jan'24 | Week starts on 20th and ends on 26th |
| 1/25/2024 | 20 Jan'24 - 26 Jan'24 | Week starts on 20th and ends on 26th |
| 1/26/2024 | 20 Jan'24 - 26 Jan'24 | Week starts on 20th and ends on 26th |
| 1/27/2024 | 27 Jan'24 - 31 Jan'24 | Week starts on 27th and ends on the last day of the month i.e 31st |
| 1/28/2024 | 27 Jan'24 - 31 Jan'24 | Week starts on 27th and ends on the last day of the month i.e 31st |
| 1/29/2024 | 27 Jan'24 - 31 Jan'24 | Week starts on 27th and ends on the last day of the month i.e 31st |
| 1/30/2024 | 27 Jan'24 - 31 Jan'24 | Week starts on 27th and ends on the last day of the month i.e 31st |
| 1/31/2024 | 27 Jan'24 - 31 Jan'24 | Week starts on 27th and ends on the last day of the month i.e 31st |

Comment: For clarity, your weeks start on Saturday (apart from the first week).

Comment: Yes, just added that in the description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following DAX Calculated Column:

```
WEEK = 
  var mnthStart = EOMONTH([Date], -1) + 1
  var mnthEnd = EOMONTH([Date], 0)
  var doWk = WEEKDAY( [Date], 2)
  var prevSat = [Date] - doWk - IF(doWk < 6, 1, -6)
  var nextFri = prevSat + 6
  var wkStart = IF(prevSat < mnthStart, mnthStart, prevSat)
  var wkEnd = IF(nextFri > mnthEnd, mnthEnd, nextFri)
  var dateFormat = "d MMM'yy"
  return FORMAT(wkStart, dateFormat) & " - " & FORMAT(wkEnd, dateFormat)
```

Comment: Omg, this is insane! You just solved this in 6 mins and my jaws drop. Thanks a ton man!